# SQL - Multiple table join and select first record on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I Have the following tables:

```
Projects (ID, Name, ManagerUser_ID)
Users(ID, Name, Active)
Delegates(ProjectID, UserID, OrderNo)
```

The `ManagerUser_ID` is the Project Manager for the project and is a link to the users table. Users, however can be `Inactive`. So, the Delegates table is a many to many table defining Users that can access the project data.

What i require, is to select the first Delegate for a project that is `Active` assuming the manager is `Inactive`. The `OrderNo` field specifies the order of the delegates (1 being first).

Some sample data:

```
Project
1, Project1, 2
2, Project2, 4
3, Project3, 1

Users
1, Joe, true
2, John, false
3, Dave, true
4, Bob, false

Delegates
1, 4, 1
1, 1, 2
1, 3, 3
2, 2, 1
2, 4, 2
2, 3, 3
```

So the output of my query would need to show:

```
Project1, Joe
Project2, Dave
Project3, Joe
```

Show Projects and Users for each project where if the `ManagerUser_ID` is inactive, then Select the `User` in `Delegates` with the lowest `OrderNo` that is `Active`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick (using window function)

```
SELECT  P.Name, ISNULL(U.Name, FirstDelegate.Name) AS ProjManager
FROM    Projects P LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Users U ON P.ManagerUser_ID = U.ID AND U.Active = 1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT * FROM
            (
                SELECT D.ProjectID, 
                       US.Name, 
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID ORDER BY OrderNo) AS SeqNo
                FROM  Delegates D INNER JOIN
                      Users US ON D.UserID = US.ID
                WHERE US.Active = 1
            ) AS Del
            WHERE Del.SeqNo = 1
        ) AS FirstDelegate ON P.ID = FirstDelegate.ProjectID
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's going to be something like this. The idea is to do an extra join (using left join) to find an earlier valid row. If you can find that row, then obviously the current row you're constructing isn't one that you want:

```
select p.Name,m.Name from Projects p inner join Users m on p.ManagerUser_ID = m.ID and m.Active = 1
union all
select
    p.Name,
    u.Name
from
    Projects p
        inner join
    Delegates d
        on
            p.ID = d.ProjectID
        inner join
    Users u
        on
            d.UserID = u.ID and
            u.Active = 1
        left join
    Delegates d_anti
        inner join
    Users u_anti
        on
            d_anti.UserID = u_anti.ID and
            u_anti.Active = 1
        on
            p.ID = d_anti.ProjectID and
            d_anti.OrderNo < d.OrderNo
where
    u_anti.ID is null
```

Comment: This looks really close, ill have to check it tomorrow. However, the final ON clause is incorrect - u_anti.OrderNo < u.OrderNo - there is no OrderNo field in Users. Im assuming this is d_anti.OrderNo < d.OrderNo?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select projectName, userName
From

(
    Select projectName, userName, row_number() over (partition by projectName order by priority ASC) as rank
    From
    (
        SELECT p.name as projectName, u.name as userName, 1 as priority
        FROM projects p INNER JOIN users u ON u.active = true and u.id = p.ManagerUser_ID

        UNION

        SELECT TOP(1) p.name, u.name, 2
        FROM Delegates d INNER JOIN projects p  ON p.id = d.projectId
                         INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = d.userId
        Where u.active = true
        Order by u.OrderNo ASC
    )
)
where rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.name, 
u.name, 
min(d.orderNo)
from projects p, 
users u, 
users manager, 
delegates d
where p.ManagerUser_ID = manager.id
and manager.active = false
and p.id = d.projectId
and d.userid = u.id
group by p.name, 
u.name
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt retreive the First Active Delegate for the project. This lists all users for the project, along with the orderNo. There needs to be a call somewhere that limits the result set to the lowest OrderNo that is active.